# Why isn't my MySQL replication filter working?

Tags: mysql, replication

```
    mysql> show slave status\G

               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event

             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: mysql.user,mysql.columns_priv,mysql.tables_priv,mysql.db,mysql.host,mysql.proxies_priv,mysql.procs_priv
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: columnstore.%
                   Last_Errno: 1286
                   Last_Error: Error 'Unknown storage engine 'columnstore'' on query. Default database: 'columnstore'. Query: 'create table columnstore.table1 (hour DATETIME, country VARCHAR(10)) engine=columnstore default charset=utf8'
```

Comment: if you want to ignore whole database, why didn't you filter on Replicate_Ignore_DB instead of Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table? do apply ignore db filter and check. Hope it helps

Comment: Is your master writing Row-based or statement on its binlog?

Comment: Mauricio, it's in MIXED mode, so probably RBR, does that matter?